# How can I synchronize two javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, html, function, time

I'm trying to make a little game project in which you have to click really fast for a small window of time.

Using the `setTimeOut()` to control the time and also a `setInterval()` to display the time left.

Yet, for the life of me, I can't seem to synchronize both timers. The timer display seems to be behind a second.

I already tried nesting the `setInterval()` inside the `setTimeout()`, but it just runs the `setTimeout()` and once its done then it starts the timer.

These are the function and the time variables I used:

```js
    let time = 10000;
    let timer = time /1000;
    setTimeout(() => {
                gameButton.style.display = "none";
                score = 0;
                power = 0;
            }, time);

    const countdown = setInterval(() => {
                textTimer.textContent = "You have " + timer + " seconds!";
                timer--;
                if (timer < 0) {
                    clearInterval(countdown);
                    textTimer.textContent = "";
                }
            }, 1000); // Update every 1 second (1000 milliseconds)
```

Comment: Just do everything in your `setInterval`.

Comment: @tkausl that would overcomplicate things, because the settimeout's logic is to be executed after 10 seconds, but the countdown is to be executed on each second. The issue is that the logic presumes that the countdown starts right away,  whereas it starts only in a second. So, the countdown needs to be called separately, besides being part of `clearInterval`.

Comment: `that would overcomplicate things, because the settimeout's logic is to be executed after 10 seconds, but the countdown is to be executed on each second.` It wouldn't overcomplicate anything. You're _already_ checking whether 10 seconds passed to actually cancel the interval. Just call your other callback aswell.

Comment: @tkausl it is an overcomplication, because the setTimeout is fundamentally about scheduling an end logic, whereas the setInterval is about what needs to be repeated. Repeatedly checking for an end-sign whereas there is a setTimeout for it does not makes sense. It makes thing superfluous. Mixing the two leads to unnecessarily check for the end of the interval upon each second, whereas we can simply schedule an event for the end. I forgot to refactor this in the previous version of my answer, thanks for pointing it out, but nevertheless, it's good to keep these separate.

Comment: agree with @tkausl.... just add it right after `textTime.textContent ="";`, If you really dont want to do that, put everything inside the interval into a function and call it once, then immediatly call the interval. Intervals do not run immediately.... the first tick happens (in your case) at 1000 milliseconds, not 0

Comment: `Mixing the two leads to unnecessarily check for the end of the interval upon each second` You have to check for the end each second anyway, to stop the interval. `it's good to keep these separate.` The problem is, timeouts and intervals __will__ unsync after some time, better just use one, either timeout or interval. To get _exact_ results, its probably best to implement a custom interval function using timeouts and calculating wait times each "tick" again.

Comment: @SoJS I think it makes more sense to separate the concerns that we have, one concern is what to do while the interval is running and another concern is what to do at the end. Indeed, we need to call the function the interval runs at once as well if we want it to start the countdown from 10. Which is obviously the intention.

Comment: @tkausl you don't have to check at the end of every second. If you schedule an event to be run after 10 seconds, then you never need to check for the end sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. So you set a timeout callback after 10 seconds and you start an interval to count down from 10 to 0. Now, your interval starts after 1 second delay and starts from 10. When it is at that state, there are 9 seconds until the end, even though it claims 10 seconds...

So on each second, it claims to have 1 more seconds. So, the solution is to create a function for the countdown, pass it in `setInterval` and call it separately as well, so it will start from the right count at the right moment and that will solve the discrepancy.

```js
    let gameButton = document.getElementById("game-button");
    let textTimer = document.getElementById("text-timer");
    let time = 10000;
    let timer = time /1000;
    let score = 0;
    let power = 0;
    setTimeout(() => {
        gameButton.style.display = "none";
        score = 0;
        power = 0;
        clearInterval(countdown);
        textTimer.textContent = "";
    }, time);
    function finalCountDown() {
        textTimer.textContent = "You have " + timer + " seconds!";
        timer--;
    }
    const countdown = setInterval(finalCountDown, 1000); // Update every 1 second (1000 milliseconds)
    finalCountDown();
```

```html
<span id="text-timer"></span>
<input id="game-button" value="click me" type="button">
```

EDIT

Now that I think of it, it makes sense to implement a mechanism in general that executes a function right away and creates an interval as well. Here it is:

```js
function setEagerInterval(c, t) {
    c();
    return setInterval(c, t);
}

let counter = 0;

setEagerInterval(function() {
    console.log(++counter);
}, 5000);
```

And we can schedule an end to it too:

```js
function setEagerInterval(c, t, e) {
    c();
    let intervalID = setInterval(c, t);
    if (!isNaN(e)) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("aloha ended");
            clearInterval(intervalID);
        }, e);
    }
}

let counter = 0;

setEagerInterval(function() {
    console.log(++counter);
}, 1000);

setEagerInterval(function() {
    console.log("aloha");
}, 500, 2400);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the relation between your interval and timeout is, that the timeout should run at the end of the interval.

Therefore, I decided to clearly show this relation in-code using [`Promise#then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then):

```js
const cbInterval = /*...*/; // (interval callback)
const cbReset = /*...*/; // (timeout callback)

interval(cbInterval, 1000).then(cbReset);
```

For this, the interval needs to be a promise; the custom `interval` function does this.

**This keeps the logic in sync** as well as the relation obvious.

"Full" example:

```js
/* Ignore; needed for code */
const textTimer = document.getElementById("timer-text");
const gameButton = document.getElementById("bt-game");

let score = 0;
let power = 0;

/* SUGGESTED CHANGES HERE */
let timer = 10; // seconds

// Previous interval logic
const cbInterval = (stop) => {
  textTimer.textContent = "You have " + timer + " seconds!";
  timer--;
  if (timer < 0) {
    stop();
  }
};

const cbReset = () => {
  // Previous interval-end logic
  textTimer.textContent = "";

  // Previous timeout logic
  gameButton.style.display = "none";
  score = 0;
  power = 0;
};

// Readable relation between previous interval and timeout logic
interval(cbInterval, 1000).then(cbReset);

// ---

/**
 * Runs an interval as a promise.
 * @param callback - a callback; first argument is a function
 *                   to stop the interval and resolve the promise
 * @param ms - milliseconds to wait between calls
 */
function interval(callback, ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let id;
    const fnStop = () => {
      clearInterval(id);
      resolve();
    };

    id = setInterval(() => {
      callback(fnStop);
    }, ms);
  });
}
```

```html
<p id="timer-text"></p>
<button id="bt-game">Play (placeholder)</button>
```

---

Instead of this `setInterval` "analog", you may also want to [look at Lajos Arpad's `setEagerInterval` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77672573/13561410).

The interval's timing/stopping may have to be adjusted.